# How do I delete data on my iPad Mini 3?

Tags: ios, ipad, data

I would like to start over on one of my games. But each time I deleted it and downloaded it again, my data was still there. I’m not sure how to get rid of it. It is updated.

Comment: I was able to find my iCloud storage in settings. But I couldn’t find the data for the app. I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on iOS 12, go to Settings -> [your name] -> iCloud -> Manage Storage

iCloud page:

[image: iCloud]

Then click on your app in the list.

Then look for your games data in the list.

Then click on it and click delete data:

[image: delete data]

This should clear all backed up data for the app. Then reinstall the app.

Alternatively, you can try and look for a setting in the game to reset your progress.

Comment: While this might delete the iCloud data for the app, it might not accomplish the OPs goal.  The app might not use iCloud to store the game data or to identify the player/device.

Comment: @fsb that is why i added "Alternatively, you can try and look for a setting in the game to reset your progress." at the end

Comment: I was more making the point that some games use 3rd-party servers to store player and progress info.  Simply removing a game (by deleting it or removing its iCloud storage) might not allow the OP to restart the game because the data is not in their control.